# Insert and update different tables in database using php ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm trying to insert data into **tbl_stock** and at the same time update **tbl_product**. I have so far written an ajax code below:

```
 <script>   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_stockin').click(function() {   
            event.preventDefault();

            /*Reading value from modal*/
            var newStock = $('#txt_addstock').val();
            var newPrice = $('#txt_addprice').val();
            if(newStock == '' && newPrice == ''){
                alert("Oops!, fill Text fields and try again.");
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST', 
                    url: 'stock-in.php',
                    data:{stock_up: newStock, cost: newPrice,
                        <?php 
                            echo 'id: "'.$row->pid.'", oldstock: "'.$row->pstock.'", productcategory: "'.$row->pcategory.'", productname: "'.$row->pname.'", currentDate : "'.$savedate.'" '
                        ?>
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#add_stock_modal').modal('hide');
                        return data;
                    }

                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

which calls **stock-in.php** and contains the following SQL codes below

```
<?php

include_once'connectdb.php';

if($_SESSION['useremail']=="" OR $_SESSION['role']=="Admin"){
    header('location:index.php');
}
if(isset($_POST['stock_up'])){
    $product_category   =   $_POST['productcategory'];
    $product_name       =   $_POST['productname'];
    $current_date       =   $_POST['currentDate'];
    $stockup            =   (int)$_POST['stock_up'];
    $newPrice           =   (int)$_POST['cost'];
    $id                 =   $_POST['id'];
    $oldstock           =   (int)$_POST['oldstock'];

    $new_stock          = $oldstock + $stockup;
    $amount_owed        = $newPrice * $stockup;
    
  try {
      //your stuff
  

    $query="insert into tbl_stock(category_name,product_name,stock_in,stock_price,total_cost,stocked_date) 
    values('$product_category','$product_name','$stockup','$newPrice','$amount_owed','$current_date')");
          $insert=$pdo->prepare($query);
          $stmt = $insert->execute();
          
          
          if($stmt){

                $sql="UPDATE `tbl_product` SET `pstock` = ?, `purchaseprice` = ? WHERE  pid= ? ";
                    $update=$pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $update->execute([$new_stock, $newPrice, $id]);

            }else{
              echo'Error in updating stock'; 
            }

          } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}
?>
```

**debug window shows values**
[image]
The insert is not working and no error is displayed. I have spent a sleepless night trying to find out why. please I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that your insert query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using prepared statements, the same way you did for the update query

Comment: `$insert->execute();` and then `if($insert){`. This is wrong, the method `execute()` **returns** a boolean, you need to get its return value instead : `$stmt = $insert->execute();` `if($stmt){`

Comment: `if($_SESSION['useremail']=="" OR $_SESSION['role']=="Admin"){` did you call `session_start();` somewhere?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. yes, I call session start. I will implement these now. thanks

Comment: By the way, what's the point using AJAX if you call `window.location.reload();` ?

Comment: to refresh the page after reloading

Comment: ```$query="insert into tbl_stock(category_name,product_name,...
    values('$product_category','$product_name','$stockup','$newPrice',...)");
          $insert=$pdo->prepare($query);
          $stmt = $insert->execute();
    
        if($stmt){``` i have implemented it but it's having same issue

Comment: "to refresh the page after reloading" ... But the whole reason Ajax was invented was to avoid having to refresh the whole page... instead you should aim to refresh only part of it, using JavaScript to update the contents, based on the response from an Ajax call. If you're just going to refresh everything as soon as Ajax finishes you might as well not bother...just do everything in a single postback request and save you and your user an extra pointless HTTP request

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have amended it but the problem still persists. prior to the insert command on **stock-in.php** it was initially updating but since i introduced the insert query it stopped. Please, what have I done wrong in the query or ajax to cause it to stop working.

Comment: It's vulnerable both to SQL injection and to unexpected syntax errors. Use parameters. HTTPS://www.phpdelusions.net/pdo . It's not impossible that this is related to your issue. If you have updated your code please edit the question to show it.

Comment: Also make sure pdo is set up to throw errors in PHP when SQL issues occur. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and of course ensure you've got error logging switched on in your PHP settings so you can go and look for those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the move to using PDO and creating Prepared Statements but then spoil the good work by embedding variables directly within the SQL commands. I couldn't test any of the following but I hope it helps.

```
<script>
    <?php
        $data=array(
            'id'                =>  $row->pid,
            'oldstock'          =>  $row->pstock,
            'productcategory'   =>  $row->pcategory,
            'productname'       =>  $row->pname,
            'currentDate'       =>  $savedate
        );
        printf('var json=%s;',json_encode($data));
    ?>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_stockin').click(function(event) {   
            event.preventDefault();

            /*Reading value from modal*/
            var newStock = $('#txt_addstock').val();
            var newPrice = $('#txt_addprice').val();
            
            if( newStock == '' && newPrice == '' ){
                alert("Oops!, fill Text fields and try again.");
            }else{
                let args={
                    stock_up:newStock,
                    cost: newPrice
                };
                
                let payload=Object.assign(args,json);
            
                $.ajax({
                    method:'POST', 
                    url:'stock-in.php',
                    data:payload,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#add_stock_modal').modal('hide');
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    
    #stock-in.php
    /*
        If you are using sessions you need to start a session!
    */
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    session_start();

    
    
    if( empty( $_SESSION['useremail'] ) OR empty( $_SESSION['role'] ) OR $_SESSION['role']=="Admin" ){
        exit( header('Location: index.php') );
    }

    /*
        Check that all fields that are required in the sql have been submitted
    */
    if( isset( 
            $_POST['stock_up'],
            $_POST['productcategory'],
            $_POST['productname'],
            $_POST['currentDate'],
            $_POST['cost'],
            $_POST['id'],
            $_POST['oldstock']
        ) ){

        try{
            
            include_once 'connectdb.php';

            /*
                When inserting, updating multiple tables there is some sense in using a transaction
                so that if one part fails the db is not littered with orphan records
            */
            $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $pdo->beginTransaction();
            
            
            
            
            $product_category   =   $_POST['productcategory'];
            $product_name       =   $_POST['productname'];
            $current_date       =   $_POST['currentDate'];
            $stockup            =   (int)$_POST['stock_up'];
            $newPrice           =   (int)$_POST['cost'];
            $id                 =   $_POST['id'];
            $oldstock           =   (int)$_POST['oldstock'];

            $new_stock          = $oldstock + $stockup;
            $amount_owed        = $newPrice * $stockup;
            
            
            /*
                The sql command should use placeholders rather than embedded fariables - the names are arbitrary
            */
            $sql='insert into `tbl_stock` ( `category_name`, `product_name`, `stock_in`, `stock_price`, `total_cost`, `stocked_date` ) 
                values 
            ( :cat, :prod, :in, :price, :cost, :date )';
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
            $args=array(
                ':cat'      =>  $product_category,
                ':prod'     =>  $product_name,
                ':in'       =>  $stockup,
                ':price'    =>  $newPrice,
                ':cost'     =>  $amount_owed,
                ':date'     =>  $current_date
            );
            if( !$stmt->execute( $args )  )echo 'stmt#1 failed';
            
            
            
            $sql='update `tbl_product` set `pstock` =:stock, `purchaseprice`=:price where `pid`=:pid';
            $stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
            $args=array(
                ':stock'    =>  $new_stock,
                ':price'    =>  $newPrice,
                ':pid'      =>  $id
            );
            if( !$stmt->execute( $args ) )echo 'stmt#2 failed';
            
            
            
            /*
                If it all went well, commit these statements to the db
            */
            if( !$pdo->commit() )echo 'commit failed';
            
            
        
        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            /*
                Any problems, rollback the transaction and report issues - 
                not necessarily with the full `getMessage()` ~ perhaps just
                'Error!' etc
            */
            $pdo->rollBack();
            
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Copied your code and it worked so perfect!!!! you're indeed a professor.

Comment: Indeed a Fearless vampire hunting professor - glad it helped though